# Using the same if-else logic in various functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, performance

I have multiple functions depending on the same if-else logic in my program. And I'm using this if-else logic inside every one of them. Since this is too much code repetition of the if-else structure, I want to turn my little program's shape into a more compact one by reducing the usage of the if-else structure.

Here is what my functions look like:

```
 function getBatteryColor(batteryLevel) {
    var batteryColor = '#2CB65C';
  // The if-else structure
    if (batteryLevel >= 75) {
        batteryColor = '#2CB65C';
    } else if (batteryLevel < 75 && batteryLevel > 50) {
        batteryColor = '#8FD601';
    } else if (batteryLevel <= 50 && batteryLevel > 25) {
        batteryColor = '#FFBF01';
    } else if(batteryLevel <= 25 && batteryLevel > 10) {
        batteryColor = '#FD894B';
    }else{
        batteryColor = '#FF554B';
    }
    return batteryColor;
}

function changeBatteryIcon(batteryLevel, iconId){
   // Define some battery icons
    var fullBatteryIcon = // full battery icon
    var threeQuarterIcon = // three quarter battery icon
    var halfBatteryIcon = // half battery icon
    var quarterBatteryIcon = // quarter battery icon
    var emptyBatteryIcon = // empty battery icon
    var batteryIcon;

   // Same if-else structure here
    if (batteryLevel >= 75) {
        batteryIcon = fullBatteryIcon;
    } else if (batteryLevel < 75 && batteryLevel > 50) {
        batteryIcon = threeQuarterBatteryIcon;
    } else if (batteryLevel <= 50 && batteryLevel > 25) {
        batteryIcon = halfBatteryIcon;
    } else if(batteryLevel <= 25 && batteryLevel > 10) {
        batteryIcon = quarterBatteryIcon;
    }else{
        batteryIcon = emptyBatteryIcon;
    }
    $('#' + iconId).replaceWith(batteryIcon)
}

/* .
   .
   .
   A couple of more functions like that, using the same if-else logic.
*/
```

What are the possible ways to reduce this if-else repetition? Can I have that if-else logic in one place (maybe in a function) and write my other functions around it? Or, maybe I could write one huge function(which might not be a good idea) to gather all the functionality of other functions inside it?

I'm kind of a rookie in javascript. I thought maybe a "promise structure | async functions" could help. But I'm not proficient in that topic too. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There is no asynchronous logic in your code, so a ”promise structure” or async/await is totally overkill and not necessary. Also, if the code works and you want to optimize it, I’d suggest asking on CodeReview instead.

Comment: `getBatteryStatus()` -> `{ color: ..., icon: ..., ... }`

Comment: If you need separate functions for each functionality then as per your code you need to check the conditions in all that functions, I think there is no other way. One thing you can do it, you can use the switch condition which is more suitable instead of using multiple if else.
Otherwise, you can create one single function that will return the battery details object containing details like icons, color, etc. based on battery level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify the conditions and return a string which represents a state and use an object for the various values.

```js
function getBatteryState(batteryLevel) {
    if (batteryLevel >= 75) return 'full';
    if (batteryLevel > 50) return 'moreThanHalf';
    if (batteryLevel > 25) return 'moreThanQuarter';
    if (batteryLevel > 10) return 'quarterOrLess';
    return 'empty';
}
```